# A fair die is rolled n times. What is the probability that at least 1 of the 6 values never appears?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A fair die is rolled $n$ times. What is the probability that at least $1$ of the $6$ values never appears? I went about calculating the complement of this, because it seemed to be easier. However, I am having trouble with it.

I was able to calculate the complement for $n=6$ and $n=7$ using a formula for putting $n$ items into $6$ boxes and requiring that each box had one item. For $n=7$ one box had to have two items and there are six ways to do that, so I accounted for this in the formula: $$\frac{6\times(7!/2!)}{6^7}$$ It seems that it will be quite complicated to apply this method for $n>7$, but I can't seem to figure out any other way. I thought to use a combination to choose the 6 from n which have to be the values $1$ through $6$: $${n\choose 6}6!/6^n$$ but this seems to undercount by quite a bit. Would the answer be something like this? This is not homework, just self-study. Thanks!

Comment: You can use inclusion-exclusion or Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think via [inclusion/exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle) the probability that at least one of the six values never appears after n rolls of the die would be:

$$p(n) = {6 \choose 1}({5 \over 6})^n - {6 \choose 2}({4 \over 6})^n + {6 \choose 3}({3 \over 6})^n - {6 \choose 4}({2 \over 6})^n + {6 \choose 5}({1 \over 6})^n$$

To understand, first just consider the probability of a 1 never showing up:

$$({5 \over 6})^n$$

Easy enough.  Now what are the chances of either a 1 never showing up OR a 2 never showing up.  To first order it's just twice the above, but by simply doubling the above, you've double-counted the events where neither a 1 nor a 2 show up, so you have to subtract that off to correct the double counting:

$$2({5 \over 6})^n - ({4 \over 6})^n$$

The final answer I gave above is just an extension of this where you first add the probability associated with the 6 ways of not rolling any particular number, then subtract off the probability of the ${6 \choose 2}$ ways of not rolling any two particular numbers, then add back in the probability of the ${6 \choose 3}$ ways of not rolling any three particular numbers, etc.

I made an A in probabilities about 25 years ago, but I haven't thought about this stuff much since, so there is a non-zero probability I'm totally wrong, but the results seem at least reasonable to me.  I think it curious and nifty that the formula works for all $n \ge 1$.  You pick an $n$ with $1 \le n \le 5$ and you get 1, but as soon as $n \ge 6$ the probability (appropriately) starts falling off:

$$p(1) = 1.00000000000000000000$$

$$p(2) = 1.00000000000000000000$$

$$p(3) = 1.00000000000000000000$$

$$p(4) = 1.00000000000000000000$$

$$p(5) = 1.00000000000000000000$$

$$p(6) = 0.98456790123456790136$$

$$p(7) = 0.94598765432098765444$$

$$p(8) = 0.88597393689986282585$$

$$...$$

$$p(100) = 0.00000007244804079771$$

Matt

Comment: I saw this decrease in the probability as well when I was doing simulations in R to check my answers when I didn't know what the formula was. But then I was just assuming the probability was 1 for n < 6. That is pretty cool and thanks for the thorough answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a practical way to allow calculating the probability with an Excel or similar. For $n=20$ I have the probability at $0.14665$. For $n=50$ I have the probability at $0.00066$.

I am assuming $n\ge6$, otherwise the probability is $1$.

The probability of not getting a $1$ is $({5\over 6})^n$. The probability of getting a $1$ and not getting a $2$ is $(1-({5\over 6})^n)({5\over 6})^n)$.

Let's define $$p = ({5\over 6})^n$$

The probability of not getting a $1$ is $p$. The probability of getting a $1$ and not getting a $2$ is $(1-p)p = p-p^2$. The probability of not getting a $1$ and/or not getting a $2$ is $p+p-p^2 =2p - p^2$. The probability of getting $1$ and $2$ and not getting $3$ is $(1-(2p-p^2))p = p-2p^2+p^3$. The probability of not getting at least one of $1$ or $2$ or $3$ is therefore $2p-p^2+p-2p^2+p^3=3p-3p^2 +p^3$.

Let's define $$q = 3p-3p^2 +p^3$$
 $q$ works for $4$, $5$ and $6$ just as it had for $1$, $2$ and $3$. So your probability for $n \ge 6$ should be $$P=2q - q^2$$